# isTargetInterceptor method of TAI is not getting called

Tags: java, single-sign-on, websphere-8

I am trying to use TAI interceptor to intercept requests coming from trusted third party that is trying to access my application. My purpose is to avoid showing Authentication page to the user since the user is already authenticated in the third party apps that i trust.

For this I have created a simple class which implements `TrustAssociationInterceptor`. I have a couple of sysouts inside the methods like 
`initialize`, `isTargetInterceptor` and `negotiateValidateandEstablishTrust`.

I have created a Jar file of this and have placed it in `\Appserver\lib\ext folder`.

I have also configured my custom TAI in the interceptors. From the WebSphere Application Server administrative console, 
navigate to `Security => Global Security =>Web and SIP security => Trust association => Enable the check box` of Enable trust association and save it => Interceptors => Click new and entered the name of my custom TAI class.

The initialize method gets called when the WebSphere server starts up. I can see the sysouts in the `\Appserver\profiles\AppSrv1\logs\server1\SystemOut.txt`.

I have created a sample web application which calls a servlet from a JSP page. 
My problem is that my custom TAI does not intercept in the middle and my request is directly going to the servlet. (I do not see any sysouts in the SystemOut.txt)

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have:

- Application security enabled (in console - `Security > Global security`)
- Your application has `Security constraints` defined in the `web.xml` as you must access protected resource for TAI to intercept.

You can enable trace `com.ibm.ws.security.*=all` to see more details in the `trace.log` during request to your application.

**UPDATE**
Here is my sample. I'm using WAS 8.5.5.1, all the methods are called:

```
// during start
[8/6/14 20:37:09:544 CEST] 00000001 TrustAssociat A   SECJ0121I: Trust Association Init class tai.TaiTest loaded successfully
[8/6/14 20:37:09:544 CEST] 00000001 SystemOut     O initialize
[8/6/14 20:37:09:544 CEST] 00000001 SystemOut     O getVersion
[8/6/14 20:37:09:544 CEST] 00000001 TrustAssociat A   SECJ0122I: Trust Association Init Interceptor signature: 1.0
[8/6/14 20:37:09:544 CEST] 00000001 SystemOut     O getType

//during stop
[8/6/14 20:40:24:338 CEST] 0000008d SystemOut     O cleanup
```

Sample code:

```
package tai;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.ibm.websphere.security.WebTrustAssociationException;
import com.ibm.websphere.security.WebTrustAssociationFailedException;
import com.ibm.wsspi.security.tai.TAIResult;
import com.ibm.wsspi.security.tai.TrustAssociationInterceptor;

public class TaiTest implements TrustAssociationInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void cleanup() {
        System.out.println("cleanup");
    }

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        System.out.println("getType");
        return "TaiTest";
    }

    @Override
    public String getVersion() {
        System.out.println("getVersion");
        return "1.0";
    }

    @Override
    public int initialize(Properties arg0)
            throws WebTrustAssociationFailedException {
        System.out.println("initialize");
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTargetInterceptor(HttpServletRequest arg0)
            throws WebTrustAssociationException {
        System.out.println("isTarget");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public TAIResult negotiateValidateandEstablishTrust(
            HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1)
            throws WebTrustAssociationFailedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Negotiate");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Application security was disabled. I tried enabling it by using the Security Configuration Wizard and got an exception - SecurityAdmin E   SECJ0074E: Error creation user registry.  The exception is com.ibm.ws.security.registry.nt.NTException: Access is denied. The problem i guess is I do not hold any admin priveleges of my system.

Comment: What registry are you using? Do you have WebSphere defined as Windows service?

Comment: Nope its not running as a Windows service. I do not have permissions to make it run as a windows service too.

Comment: That's good. So what kind of registry Local OS? Switch to Federated, you should be able to test you interceptor then.

Comment: Did so. Now I am getting com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 56  completed: No. Tried changing the ports of server but still the prblem persists.

Comment: Either your server didn't fully stop (ensure you dont have java process), or you still have some ports used by other programs.

Comment: I created a server and a new profile and configured it again which resolves this. But I have a unique problem now. The initialize,type and cleanup methods get called when the server is stopped. The initialize method does not get called when the server starts up.

Comment: Badly stuck with this. Any quick help is appreciated.